# Could not convert string to float using dtype in nparray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a raw `np.array()` on which I would explicitly indicate the type of the column.

The `data` array has the following form:

```
data = [
    [name1, float1, float2, float3]
    # ... 
    [nameX, floatX, floatX, floatX]
]
```

Now, to explicitly specify the column type, I do the following:

```
data = np.array(data, dtype=[('name', str), ('amount0', float), ('amount1', float), ('amount2', float)])
```

Quite straight forward.

However, for some reason I do not understand I got the following error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'john_smith'

And `'john_smith'` is a value from the first column of data (`data[:,0]`), since I defined this to be a string, I don't even understand why it tries to convert it to a float.

Also: `'john_smith'` is neither the first or the last element of the data array.

So, what is wrong here?

**Working example**:

```
import numpy as np

row1 = ['julien', '6270', '17', '0.2703992365198028']
row2 = ['john_smith', '2983', '10', '0.3341129301703976']
row3 = ['helo', '19', '0', '0.0']

data = []
data.append(row1)
data.append(row2)
data.append(row3)
data = np.array(data)

data = np.array(data, dtype=[('name', str), ('amount0', float), ('amount1', float), ('amount2', float)])
```

Comment: you should give a *minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example*

Comment: Is your argument to `dtype` wrapped in a list, or is there a type in what you've posted here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The argument of my `dtype` are given into my code:  `dtype=[('name', str), ('amount0', float), ('amount1', float), ('amount2', float)])`. Or may be I don't understand your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how structured arrays work. You don't specify the data type of a "column", you specify a the datatype of a *structure*, and you build an array of structs. `Numpy` arrays are homogeneous arrays, you cannot have mixed datatypes. So, you could do this:

```
>>> e1 = ('julien', 6270, 17, 0.2703992365198028)
>>> e2 = ('john_smith', '2983', '10', '0.3341129301703976')
>>> e3 = ('helo', '19', '0', '0.0')
>>> data = [e1, e2, e3]
>>> arr = np.array(data, dtype=[('name', '<U255'), ('amount0', float), ('amount1', float), ('amount2', float)])
>>> arr
array([('julien', 6270.0, 17.0, 0.2703992365198028),
       ('john_smith', 2983.0, 10.0, 0.3341129301703976),
       ('helo', 19.0, 0.0, 0.0)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U255'), ('amount0', '<f8'), ('amount1', '<f8'), ('amount2', '<f8')])
>>>
```

But notice,

```
>>> arr.shape
(3,)
```

*There are no columns*. Of course, we can just pretend like there were:

```
>>> arr['name']
array(['julien', 'john_smith', 'helo'],
      dtype='<U255')
>>> arr[0]['name']
'julien'
```

But honestly, it sounds like you really want a `pandas.DataFrame`

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'amount0', 'amount1', 'amount2'])
         name amount0 amount1             amount2
0      julien    6270      17            0.270399
1  john_smith    2983      10  0.3341129301703976
2        helo      19       0                 0.0
>>>
```

Notice, I had to modify your `str` datatype to accept `unicode`, because `numpy` interprets `str` as byte-strings. You could always makes your strings `bytes` objects by encoding them. This is probably the way to go if you are only working with ascii characters.

Answer (score 1):

Data supplied to numpy.array should be a list of tuples, not list of lists.  Your example needs two changes - rows are tuples and don't convert data into array.

```
import numpy as np

row1 = ('julien', '6270', '17', '0.2703992365198028')
row2 = ('john_smith', '2983', '10', '0.3341129301703976')
row3 = ('helo', '19', '0', '0.0')

data = []
data.append(row1)
data.append(row2)
data.append(row3)

data = np.array(data, dtype=[('name', str), ('amount0', float), ('amount1', float), ('amount2', float)])
```